# Angular 4 as iframe, call parent function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, iframe

I have an issue with a project. I have a web page that has to use an angular 4 app. I must use an iframe to have this app on my page.

Now, when I want to call a parent function from the app (so from the iframe) when I build the app, I have a compilation error because the angular app doesn't know the parent's function. I understand that, but I don't know if there is any other way to call a parent function from an angular 4 iframe.

Here is what I tried : `parent.barcode();`

I hope that someone could help me with my issue!

Thanks

Comment: Maybe "window.postMessage" will be a opportunity for you (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Comment: I tried that today and it didn't work either. But I've found a solution using jQuery. I didn't think about that but you can access the parent with the command : $('#your_id', window.parent.document)
Then you can add .val(), .attr(), .css(), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I've found a solution. I don't have to try to communicate that way, I needed to change some input fields of the parent window, from the iframe.

But I didn't think about JQuery, and I can edit my parent window with that command : `$("#your_id", window.parent.document)`. And then you can change a value with `.val()`, set the css with `.css()`, add an attribute with `.attr()`, etc.

I hope this could help anyone!